# why does bower hang when installing?

Tags: bower

`$ bower install angular-animate  --save 
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.18
bower validate      1.2.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.18
bower validate      1.2.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.18
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.18
bower validate      1.2.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2.*
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.18
bower validate      1.2.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.0.8
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.18
bower validate      1.2.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.0.0 <1.4.0`

Comment: Can you in stall other components? Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes, I installed jQuery fine. Infact, it installed fine in /tmp, just not in my app. I copied over my bower.json and it still installed ok in /tmp. Something in my project directory seems to be causing it to hang.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I removed `bower_components` and reinstalled and it worked fine. Another thing that fixed the problem of resolving dependencies was to run `bower cache clean`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue but I was having the same problem today using bower to install angular sanitize, and wanted to add my two cents, in case someone has this issue again. Not sure if this is the best solution but it worked. I added the force flag

```
bower install angular-animate  --save --force
```

you can also try before:

```
bower cache clean

bower cache list
```

Also I deleted the libraries that bower had pulled in previously